# Is possible bind :src to a variable?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm trying to bind the `src` attribute to a variable managed by `Vuex`, so I did:

```html
<img
    class="navbar-brand-item"
    v-bind:src="{ 'assets/images/logo-light.png' : isNavbarLight, 'assets/images/logo.png' : !isNavbarLight }"
    alt="Logo"
/>
```

the variable `isNavbarLight` is taken from the `Vuex` store:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Header',
  setup() {
    const store = useStore()
    const isNavbarLight = computed(() => store.state.isNavbarLight)
    return {
      isNavbarLight
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

and it's a `boolean` variable which allow me to change the type of logo based on the page color. This is the `Vuex` store implementation:

```js
import { Commit, createStore } from 'vuex';
    
export default createStore({
  state: {
    isNavbarLight: false 
  },
  mutations: {
    setNavbarLight: (state: {isNavbarLight: boolean}, value: boolean) => state.isNavbarLight = value
  },
  actions: {
    setNavbarLight: ({commit}: {commit: Commit}, value: boolean) => commit('setNavbarLight', value)
  },
  modules: {}
});
```

The issue is that as final result I get:

```html
<img class="navbar-brand-item" src="[object Object]" alt="Logo">
```

how is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's possible, but right now you are trying to bind it to an object that has two boolean properties!

```html
<img
    class="navbar-brand-item"
    v-bind:src="isNavbarLight ? 'assets/images/logo-light.png' : 'assets/images/logo.png'"
    alt="Logo"
/>
```

This is how you can use a statement with a ternary operator to switch between the two image URLs, or you could use a computed property or a value from the Vuex store, as long as it returns a string, because that's what the `src` attribute requires.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correct you need to add a condition so you can achieve it by using a computed property like this

```js
....
computed: {
   logoSrc(){
      return this.isNavbarLight? 'assets/images/logo-light.png' : 'assets/images/logo.png';
   }
}
....
```

and inside the `src` attribute you will just write it like this

```html
<img :src="logoSrc">
```